# How to find a function which is declared in a .h file in C?

Tags: c

I want to find the specific definitions of some functions which are declared in a .h file. The question is how I can accomplish that? Because there're hundreds of .c files in the directory. And I have tried to use grep command, it doesn't work efficiently. Is there any other method?

Slice of my .h file:

248    #define EXPAND(a,b,c) a b

I use vim, so:

```
:tag EXPAND
```

E433: No tags file
E426: tag not found
248, etc. is the line number. and 433, 426 has no relation with EXPAND, one is a blank line, the other is within a comment section.

EXPAND is a macro? I thought it was a function because it appeared in other .c files like:

```
u[EN] = EXPAND(v[VX]*v[VX], + v[VY]*v[VY], + v[VZ]*v[VZ])
```

@didierc is right, I found this is a macro. I'm really green to C. Many thanks to @Basile Starynkevitch, offered a way to trace a function, that's another prob. puzzled me

Comment: "one question per question", please.

Comment: And which operating system?

Comment: mac, I work in bash.

Comment: @Schawn: you probably mean MacOSX

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: Genau. It's MacOS X10.

Comment: Edit your question to improve it and give the precise commands that you have tried.

Comment: I don't get it: `EXPAND` is a macro, it doesn't have any other definition than what you've shown.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`etags`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/etags.html) with `emacs` (or else [`ctags`](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/), e.g. if using `vi`). Instead of `grep` consider using [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/).

Read more about the [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) (e.g. [Levine's book *Linkers & Loaders*](http://www.iecc.com/linker/); details are operating system specific); on Linux see [binutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/). Notice that `extern`applies to *declarations*, not *definitions* of function or variable names.

Don't forget to run the `ctags` or `etags` command from time to time, and before using tags in your `emacs` or `vi` editor.

About macros: please understand that the [C preprocessor](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) is the first phase of compilation. Read documentation of [GNU `cpp`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/). Don't expect macros to be functions, they are textual devices! Use perhaps `gcc -Wall -C -E foo.c > foo.i` (with some more options to `gcc`, e.g. `-I` and `-D` ones) to get the preprocessed form `foo.i` of source file `foo.c`; look inside the generated `foo.i` with  your editor.

Comment: `ctags` works well with `Vi` too :)

Comment: I tried your way but failed. This is a slice in my .h file: "#define EXPAND(a,b,c) a b" Error: No tags file \n tag not found: EXPAND.

Comment: Edit your question to show the command with `etags` that you have run.